# Show Welcome Message in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5.3

**My Laravel Code is here**

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
    @if (Auth::guest())
        {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
    @else
        Welcome {!! \Auth::user()->UserName !!}
    @endif
</a>
```

**I am trying to convert this into Angular Js**

Here is my code in Html.

```
<a class="navbar-brand">
    {{WelcomeMessage}}
</a>
```

**and code in Controller**

```
myApp.controller("NavController", ["$scope", "UserModel", function($scope, UserModel) {

    $scope.WelcomeMessage = function() {
        debugger;
        if(typeof UserModel.GetUserObject() !== "undefined") {
            return "Welcome " + UserModel.GetUserObject().UserName;
        }
        else {
            return "Welcome ";
        }
    };
}]);
```

Controller reference is present in layout file but due to some reasons it is not even hitting debugger.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything at all to do with laravel, this is definitely an Angular question.  And to that end, you are using `WelcomeMessage` like a variable in the HTML, but declared it as a function.  You *could* use `{{WelcomeMessage()}}`, but this function will be executed every digest cycle;  you would be better to set the value in the controller.

Comment: @Claies : Thanks for correcting the code. WelcomeMessage function is a function which evaluates if user session is present or not and based on that shows the message. How could I stop it's execution on every digest cycle by setting it's value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This controller code could be simplified to set the value at controller initialization.

```
myApp.controller("NavController", ["$scope", "UserModel", function($scope, UserModel) {
    if (UserModel.GetUserObject() !== null) {
      $scope.WelcomeMessage = "Welcome " + UserModel.GetUserObject().UserName;
    } else {
      $scope.WelcomeMessage = "Welcome ";
    }
  }
]);
```

it could be consolidated even more by using a ternary operator:

```
myApp.controller("NavController", ["$scope", "UserModel", function($scope, UserModel) {
    $scope.WelcomeMessage = "Welcome " + 
                        (UserModel.GetUserObject() ? UserModel.GetUserObject().UserName : "");
]);
```

However, in this case, none of this is even necessary, since the output is the same;  `$scope.WelcomeMessage = "Welcome " + UserModel.GetUserObject().UserName;` would return `"Welcome "` if `UserModel.GetuserObject().UserName` is `null` without the need to do any of these `null` checks.  In JavaScript, it is generally unnecessary to do `null` checks unless you are planning to assign something *into* the possibly `null` object property.

In other words, the following code should be all that is really necessary:

```
myApp.controller("NavController", ["$scope", "UserModel", function($scope, UserModel) {
    $scope.WelcomeMessage = "Welcome " +  UserModel.GetUserObject().UserName;
]);
```

This will only execute the `UserModel.GetUserObject()` function a single time.

Comment: It ran 3 times, if I use function..really annoying situation so far. I tried to use global variable as written by you. Is there any way to check how many times the variable was evaluated?

Comment: I was trying to tell about this code sniplet `$scope.WelcomeMessage = "Welcome " + 
                        (UserModel.GetUserObject() ? UserModel.GetUserObject.UserName : "");` I am sorry, I am a beginner only.

Comment: that is a ternary operator, it's not a global snippet;  it should go in the controller.  I'll update the answer for better clarity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41091169/route-issue-in-profile-page Could you kindly suggest something here?